# c++ trying to pipe string input to 2dmatrix

Tags: c++, cin

My source code is below:

```
string** field = new string*[m]; //initialise a mxn Matrix=> field.
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) { // we do this because the compiler does not know the ammount of memory required in advance hence use of poitners. 
    field[i] = new string[n]; 
}

for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        cin >> &field[i][j];
    }
}
```

I am having trouble trying to push the input from cin to my 2d matrix field. I have tried double dereferencing ie. &&field, but still get the same error. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `cin >> field[i][j];`

Comment: Let say you had a single `string` you wanted to read from the user, how would you do that? Like e.g. `string s; cin >> s;`? It's no different when the string is part of an array, no matter how many "dimensions".

Comment: And a small unrelated tip: Don't use pointers and dynamic allocation unless it's part of the assignment. Use `std::vector` if you need a run-time dynamic "array".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initially wrote cin >> field[i][j] but got confused because intellisense said no operator matches operands of type std::istream and std::string. To solve that problem I had to import string The corrected code is below:

```
    #include <string>;

//...
    string** field = new string*[m]; //initialise a mxn Matrix=> field.
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) { // we do this because the compiler does not know the ammount of memory required in advance hence use of poitners. 
        field[i] = new string[n]; 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cin >> field[i][j];
        }
    }
```